# Object reference not set to an instance of an object., model is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to display a checklist that gets data from MySQL Database and displays it in a view and updates the value of the variable (IsChecked) of each element in the table by whether we have checked the amenity or not (i am displaying some amenities). The model of the view is Hotel_5.ViewModel.BookingRoom, where BookingRoom is a custom model i created where i use multiple models. I get the exception at Model.AmenitiesList.Count(). The model is null.

This is my view

```
<div class="form-group">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AmenitiesList.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AmenitiesList[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "form-control" });
                        <label>@Model.AmenitiesList[i].amenityType</label>
                             //If you need to hide any values and get them in your post
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AmenitiesList[i].AmenityId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AmenitiesList[i].AmenityPrice)
                    }
            </div>
```

This is my ViewModel

```
public class BookingRoom
    {
        public Bookings bookings { get; set; }
        public Rooms rooms { get; set; }
        public List<Amenities> AmenitiesList { get; set; } = new List<Amenities>();
    }
```

This is my Amenities Model

```
public class Amenities
    {
        [Key]
        public int AmenityId { get; set; }
        public double AmenityPrice { get; set; }
        public AmenityType amenityType { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }

    public enum AmenityType
    {
        tv,
        wi_fi,
        hair_dryer,
        help
    }
```

Comment: How do you call the View? Please add the code in the controller action related to this view.

Comment: You have to put a check before iterating through the list: `@if (Model != null && Model.Amenities != null)`. That way, on a _get_ request, you will have a null check on the model and the _AmenitiesList_.

Comment: Given you've tagged entity-framework I'll assume both `BookingRoom` and `Amenities` are coming from an ef query. I suspect you need to `Include` amenities when querying the `BookingRoom`, so for example `var bookings = await context.BookingRooms.Include(x => x.AmenitiesList).ToListAsync()` (more info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Answer (score 0):

When Querying you should Include its `AmenitiesList` too, otherwise it will be null:

In Controller:

```
var bookingRoom = context.BookingRooms.Include(b => b.AmenitiesList).FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == someId);
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

please note that what I queried might not be what you want, it is just to demonstrate how to use `Include()` and also you should add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.